# How can i call the private method in controller by link_to in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my controller called `scenario_population`

```
def scenario_population
 .....
end
```

I have a `link_to` method in view

```
<%= name_id %> #without form
<%= link_to 'Run', # %>
```

How can i call the controller method by `link_to` button here? I don't have created any routes for the private method in controller.

Please suggest me to get this?  Thanks

Comment: You want to execute the controller method when someone clicks on that link?

Comment: Okay why isn't it public? So far off the rails you've gone into orbit round neptune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all 'link_to' does is create a link element, it will need a url to put as the link's href. So what you're looking to do is impossible. You'll have to create a public route to access your controller method.